# Setting seed on train_test_split sklearn python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, train-test-split

is there any way to set seed on train_test_split on python sklearn. I have set the parameter `random_state` to an integer, but I still can not reproduce the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x = [k for k in range(0, 10)]
y = [k for k in range(0, 10)]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=11)
print (x_train)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=11)
print (x_train)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=11)
print (x_train)
```

The above code will produce the same result for x_train every time I split the data. It is possible that the randomness is in your dataframe, not train_test_split.

Answer (score 2):

simply in `train_test_split`, specify the parameter `random_state=some_number_you_wan to use,` like `random_state=42`